# What are the possible ways to collect a form's data inside another form?

Tags: php, forms

I believe we can't nest a form inside another. But my situation requires something of the sort to solve it. Please suggest possible way to resolve it.

There's a form to collect all the info of a product to be newly uploaded into database. Now I need to allow the user to add multiple sizes for each product before submitting the form.

I thought of using session for submitting multiple sizes but it doesn't seem to be the perfect solution.

Any help is appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Dont add multiple forms. Use one forms and allow javascript to add more elements to it on runtime and use a good naming convention. For example if there can be multiple `weight` values for a product you can name the weight field like `weight[]` and then in PHP you will get a nice array of all the posted weights

Comment: whad do you mean by multiple sizes??

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky if it can be solved by javascript to add more element on runtime I shall try it out.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is not valid HTML or XHTML. There is no guarantee for cross-browser support. You should simply not do this.
The official specifications states that:

"form must not contain other form elements."
http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions (XHTML Specs Section B. "Element Prohibitions")

"Every form must be enclosed within a FORM element. There can be several forms in a single document, but the FORM element can't be nested." (HTMl 3.2 Specs)

Althrough there are workarounds for that. Try this one.
http://blog.avirtualhome.com/how-to-create-nested-forms/

Answer (score 0):

Just use one form, as Marcus Rommel mentioned, it's not good practice to nest forms.
 
You haven't given much info in your question, but as far as I can tell, you want your users to input a large range of sizes per product, how about this:

```
<form role="form">
  <div>
    <label for="InputProduct">Product</label>
    <select>
      <option>Product 1</option>
      <option>Product 2</option>
      <option>Product 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="InputProductNumber">How Many?</label>
    <input type="number" max="10" placeholder="Small Size">
    <input type="number" max="10" placeholder="Medium Size">
    <input type="number" max="10" placeholder="Large Size">
  </div>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Of course, you can create more product selects per product, then have a number input per size.

Answer (score 0):

Like Hanky 웃 Panky suggested.

```
 <form>
  here you add your normal fields.
 <dev id='addable'>
  here the default no of elements
 </dev>
 <button onclick='addElement()'>
 </form>
```

**Disclaimer:** This is only the outline provided that you didn't give anycodes.

```
 <script>
 function addElement() {
 document.getElementById("addable").innerHTML += "here you add the element code you want"; 
 //i.e. "<input name="size[]" type="text"/>"
 }
 </script>
```

For more methods to how to make it, kindly search for "javascript add more elements to form".

Comment: I search using the exact keywords you mentioned and came across this seacrh result:http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/21/how-to-dynamically-add-form-elements-via-javascript/

Comment: And I'm unable to submit the main form ...if I remove the form tag for the nested form and just use div,then can submit

Comment: Yes there is no need for a nested form.

I meant by my code the whole form.